# Not able to connect to cassandra from host machine

Tags: docker, cassandra

I have configured a cassandra node on my mac book pro using docker as follows

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "tcp-port7191,tcp,,7191,,7191"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "tcp-port7000,tcp,,7000,,7000"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "tcp-port7001,tcp,,7001,,7001"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "tcp-port9160,tcp,,7160,,7160"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "tcp-port9042,tcp,,9042,,9042"
```

(restart machine)

```
docker run --name c1 -v /Users/MyProjects/scripts/:/script -d cassandra:latest -p "7191:7191" -p "7000:7000" -p "7001:7001" -p "9160:9160" -p "9042:9042"
```

I can easily do

```
docker exec -it c1 cqlsh
```

it says

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.1 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
```

Now I get the IP address of my virtual box vm using

```
docker-machine env default
```

I can see the IP address of `192.168.99.100`

But when I run my java program to connect to the same cassandra instance using the IP address above. I get an error

```
    00:00:56.611 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[/192.168.99.100:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Error connecting to /192.168.99.100:9042 (Connection refused: /192.168.99.100:9042)
00:00:56.615 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Host.STATES - Defuncting Connection[/192.168.99.100:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] because: [/192.168.99.100] Cannot connect
00:00:56.616 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[/192.168.99.100:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true] closing connection
00:00:56.617 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Host.STATES - [/192.168.99.100:9042] preventing new connections for the next 1000 ms
00:00:56.617 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Host.STATES - [/192.168.99.100:9042] Connection[/192.168.99.100:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true] failed, remaining = 0
00:00:56.624 [run-main-0] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] error on /192.168.99.100:9042 connection, no more host to try
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.99.100] Cannot connect
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:157) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:140) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680) ~[netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:603) ~[netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:563) ~[netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424) ~[netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:276) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:292) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) ~[netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.99.100:9042
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289) ~[netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:4.0.33.Final]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
00:00:56.625 [run-main-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Shutting down
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.abhi.connector.CassandraConnector$class.$init$(CassandraConnector.scala:8)
    at com.abhi.models.Movies$.<init>(Movies.scala:25)
    at com.abhi.models.Movies$.<clinit>(Movies.scala)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation$$anonfun$storeInCassandra$1.apply(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala:55)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation$$anonfun$storeInCassandra$1.apply(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation$.storeInCassandra(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala:55)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation$.main(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala:51)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation.main(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.99.100:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.99.100] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:231)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1414)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:162)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:333)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:283)
    at com.abhi.connector.Connector$.<init>(CassandraConnector.scala:22)
    at com.abhi.connector.Connector$.<clinit>(CassandraConnector.scala)
    at com.abhi.connector.CassandraConnector$class.$init$(CassandraConnector.scala:8)
    at com.abhi.models.Movies$.<init>(Movies.scala:25)
    at com.abhi.models.Movies$.<clinit>(Movies.scala)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation$$anonfun$storeInCassandra$1.apply(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala:55)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation$$anonfun$storeInCassandra$1.apply(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation$.storeInCassandra(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala:55)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation$.main(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala:51)
    at com.abhi.MovieLensDataPreperation.main(MovieLensDataPreperation.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

This is my code to configure the java connection

```
Cluster.builder()
  .addContactPoints("192.168.99.100").withPort(9042)
  .build()
```

Edit: I also replaced the above IP address with the IP address of docker guest VM... but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: What values are configured for `rpc_address` or `rpc_interface` in your `cassandra.yaml`?

Comment: rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160

Comment: Can you connect with cqlsh on the cassandra host itself when using the IP instead of `localhost`?

Comment: no. `MacBook-Pro-2:~$ docker exec -it c1 cqlsh 192.168.99.100
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.99.100': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.99.100', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

Comment: That might be a stupid question, but are you sure you got the IP right? What if you configure `rpc_interface` instead of `rpc_address`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS when creating the docker container

This is the command I used

```
docker run --name c1 -v /Users/MyProjects/scripts/:/script -d -p "7191:7191" 
-p "7000:7000" -p "7001:7001" -p "9160:9160" -p "9042:9042" -e 
CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.99.100 cassandra:latest
```

After creating the container like this. I am able to connect from my Scala application with this code

```
  val keyspace: KeySpace = new KeySpace("foo")

  val cluster =
    Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPoint("192.168.99.100").withPort(9042)
      .build()

  cluster.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(100000);
  val session: Session = cluster.connect(keyspace.name)
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time

Comment: Could you please please explain the CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS environment variable? Why did you chose this address?